# Getting Jodd Jerry: NoClassDefFoundError - jodd/exception/UncheckedException

Tags: java, jquery, noclassdeffounderror, jodd

I am trying to use [Jerry](http://jodd.org/doc/jerry/index.html) module from Jodd in my java project, for that i downloaded 
**jodd-lagarto- 3.4.5** jar and added in classpath. I started write the code like below.

```
public void testJerryParserCreation() {

    Jerry.JerryParser jerryParser = Jerry.jerry();
    ((LagartoDOMBuilder) jerryParser.getDOMBuilder()).enableXmlMode();

    Jerry doc = jerryParser.parse("<xml>   <book isbn='123'> <name>Foo<br></name>   </book></xml>");

    Jerry name = doc.$("book name");

    assertEquals("Foo", name.text());

    assertEquals("<xml><book isbn=\"123\"><name>Foo<br></br></name></book></xml>", doc.html());
}
```

but in the above test in the first line itself, it is giving following exception. what might be the wrong here. Is my jar not correct?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jodd/exception/UncheckedException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at jodd.jerry.Jerry$JerryParser.createLagartoDOMBuilder(Jerry.java:82)
    at jodd.jerry.Jerry$JerryParser.<init>(Jerry.java:75)
    at jodd.jerry.Jerry.jerry(Jerry.java:123)
    at com.veersoft.JerryParserTest.testJerryParserCreation(JerryParserTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jodd.exception.UncheckedException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple:) `jodd-lagarto` module depends on `jodd-core` module that has the missing class (as well as other utils Lagarto is using). Check the [download page](http://jodd.org/download/index.html) to see all modules and dependencies. For your version there might be also a dependency on `slf4j` logger (this has been removed recently).

You may also consider using some dependency management tool, like *gradle* or *maven*. Than all dependencies will be automatically downloaded.

If possible, try using the latest version of **Jodd** :) At this moment it's 3.4.10; 3.5 is almost out. The new versions contain some important Lagarto-related improvements, fixes and performance boosting :) Enjoy!

Comment: may i know what is the difference between jodd-lagarto and jodd-lagarto-web

Comment: Sure. `jodd-lagarto` is pure parser, containing `LagartoDOM` and `Jerry` and `CSSelly` - all tools for parsing. `jodd-lagarto-web` contains several web-related tools (therefore, it depends on servlets) - `Decora` (html decorators), `HTMLStapler` - stacks resources into one file, `HtmlStrip` removes empty spaces etc...

Comment: Thank you for your reply, so i can use (jodd-lagarto or jodd-lagarto-web) in my webapplication. I think i should use jodd-lagarto-web right?

Comment: Hm, its not a matter what is better, but what you need. If you need just parsing than you just use `jodd-lagarto`. if you need other tools, described above, use `jodd-lagarto-web`.

Comment: In the Jodd.org site itself ,They are saying like "Jerry belongs to jodd-lagarto module and has no dependencies." I think as you said that jodd-lagarto is there without any dependencies, Could you please send me link to download latest jar.

Comment: Thats because the site is talking about latest version, 3.5.0, that is just about to be released. Its hard to maintain all that:)

Comment: Actually i have built total jodd project with all the modules using 'gradle', So it has created jars(3.5.0), can i use jodd-lagarto-3.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in my own project.

Comment: Sure, of course! Still you will need the `jodd-core` jar and `jodd-log`. When said 'no dependencies' - in the site - it means no _external_ dependencies. That has to be clarified, you are right :)

Comment: No. `lodd-lagarto` depends on `jodd-core` (as always) and `jodd-log` (before 3.5 it was slf4j).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47241/discussion-between--and-m-s-naidu)

Comment: No problem, feel free to mark the answer if it resolves your problem.

Comment: can you please tell me, can i use these jars in the production also?

Comment: You can use all jodd jars in production.

Comment: Please clarify small doubt, Actually i have built total jodd project with all the modules using 'gradle', So it has created jars(3.5.0), can i use jodd-lagarto-3.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, jodd-log-3.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, jodd-core-3.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in my own project, Which are like snapshots, will i use all these three jars in production.

Comment: Try again :) 3.5 was released yesterday:)

Comment: thank you, should i built the project again to get the latest jerry jars.